# How can I stop OSQA spammers?

Tags: spam-prevention, osqa

I host a OSQA website on AWS EC2. Recently, I keep getting a lot of spammers (7000+) signing up and posting stupid poker-related questions. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

My questions are:

- how did they do that?
- how can I stop/prevent those spammers?